# How to reposition a form in Access through code?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I want to move a form to the screen's left side in Access 2007 in the `onOpen` event. I've not found how to do it using form properties, because top and left properties seems to be read only through code during runtime.

Do I need call API methods to move a form in Access to another position on screen? Is there a quick way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at Access' Help topic for the `Move` method.

This sample is code behind a command button which will re-position the current form.  If you supply the `Width` and `Height` arguments, you can also use `Move` to resize the form.

```vb
Private Sub cmdMoveForm_Click()
    'Me.Move Left:=0, Top:=0, Width:=400, Height:=300 '
    Me.Move Left:=2970, Top:=1860
End Sub
```

Note the numbers are in twips: 1440 twips per inch; or 567 twips per centimeter.