# Setting height for a form

Tags: ms-access

I have a questionnaire form on MS Access, `frmQuestionnaire` and it is quite large vertically. I am having an issue with it's sizing. I want it to centered and be 20cm wide (I have set this value in the Form Width under Design view) by 20cm tall.

If I turn auto `Auto Resize` on, the form ends up being 20cm wide but it's length gets set to the entire 38cm (I don't if it matters but I am using a header and footer too, so the overall height is probably more). This makes the form trail off the bottom of my screen. Turning `Auto Resize` off results in what I can assume only to be a random width (it's probably 5cm wider than what I set my form to) and a much better height (although, I am not sure how it comes up with the height). This leaves in horrible looks whitespace to the right of my form.

I have tried programmatically setting `InsideHeight` and this works but the Form is no longer vertically centered.

I have also tried using `frmQuestionnaire` as a subform as part of a new form and this works visually but breaks all the `on event's`. I can probably spend time and fix them but this is very hacky and I would rather not go this route.

Comment: 1. Is this a popup or full-screen form? 2. Continuous or single form? 3. In Options - Current database - Document Window Options, what have you selected, Tabbed Documents or Overlapping Windows? -- have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34321906/3820271

Comment: Consider the [Form.Move Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845906.aspx) to adjust the size and position of your form.  Also [How to reposition a form in Access through code?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6572949/77335)